# How works HTTPS encryption works?

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

Is the entire request sent encrypted or only the payload

Comment: The entire request and response are sent over the encrypted channel.

Comment: Please try to stick to the technical question it self next time.
Essentially the question is flowing 
"Is entire request sent encrypted or only payload"